# Checkerboard inside a window using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am new here and I hope someone could be so kind and help me out.

I am currently trying to create a checkers game and therefore need to create the board. I have already checked other answers but they never seem to create the board inside another window (where I will later put buttons to resign and start a new game). Right now, only one rectangle is displayed, even though I have created several in a loop.

Does anyone know why this is?
Here my code

First: Checkersboard class, which creates the rectangles of the board

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;

public class CheckersBoard extends Pane {

private int boardWidth = 10;
private int boardHeight = 10;


private Rectangle[][] board;


public CheckersBoard() {
    // Declares new board
    board = new Rectangle[boardWidth][boardHeight];

    // Initializes new board
    for(int x=0; x < boardWidth; x++){
        for(int j=0; j < boardHeight; j++){
            board[x][j] = new Rectangle();
            board[x][j].setWidth(50);
            board[x][j].setHeight(50);
            board[x][j].setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            board[x][j].setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
            board[x][j].setStrokeWidth(1);
        }
    }

    // Generates colours for the chessboard backgrounds
    for(int x=0; x < boardWidth; x++){
        for(int j=0; j < boardHeight; j++){
            if((x%2==0 && j%2==1) || (x%2==1 && j%2==0)){
            board[x][j].setFill(Color.PINK);
            }
            else if((x%2==0 && j%2==0) || (x%2==1 && j%2==1)){
            board[x][j].setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void placeboard(final int i, final int j){
    getChildren().add(board[i][j]);
}
}
```

Second, the main class where the board is added to the other window and then displayed:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import .... ;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        CheckersBoard board = new CheckersBoard();

        GridPane root = (GridPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view/Base.fxml"));

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                board.placeboard(i, j);
            }
        }
        root.add(board, 0, 0);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
              scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

And finally my fxml-file "Base" with the almost empty gridpane:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<GridPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="test" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Thank you all already for your help! :)

Kind regards, Lisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the rectangles are at `(0,0)`. You need to set the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
board[x][j].setX(x * 50); // 50 being the width of each rectangle
board[x][j].setY(y * 50); // 50 being the height of each rectangle
```